# Is there a <type_traits> implementation for VC6?

Tags: c++, stl, type-traits, tr1, visual-studio-6

Are there any working  implementations for Visual C++ 6? Specifcally I'm looking for `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same`and `std::remove_cv`.

Comment: You can roll out your own, the mechanisms existed in the standard since c++98

Comment: Can you use [`boost::type_traits`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: I did a search of that documentation and there are no results for `enable_if`.

Comment: @StoryTeller I would like a drop-in solution as I don't know how to implement this library or these functions.

Comment: [It's not too difficult](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). As the possible implementation section demonstrates.

Comment: I tried that too before posting to SO. It doesn't work with VC6: `error C2182: '__formal' : illegal use of type 'void'`.

Comment: Did you happen to use it like this `enable_if<condition>::type variable`?

Comment: I'm trying to see if this is possible in VC6: https://ideone.com/tW4GVE

Comment: VC6 does not support SFINAE so you might find it difficult.